# How to find the first missing number in each gap of consequent numbers?

Tags: r

I have a series of numbers between 1 to 10 in ascending order which some numbers are missing. I want to find the first number for each missing gap. I'm doing this in R. For example:

```
numbers=c(1,2,5,6,7,10)
```

the numbers missing are 3,4 and 8,9 so I want to find 3 and 8:

```
3
8
```

any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `diff` and subsetting as follows

```
numbers[diff(numbers) != 1] + 1
[1] 3 8
```

`diff(numbers) != 1` will return a logical vector where adjacent elements are not equal to the next number in the "counting" order. `numbers[]` will subset these, then add 1 to return the missing values.